# Openconnect not able to connect to gateway

Tags: openssl, ubuntu-14.04, openconnect

I am not able to connect via openconnect VPN client from my ubuntu 14.04 system. I used to connect to to this VPN 1 month back and since then I had not made any changes to the VPN client settings.

This is the error I am getting in the logs.

```
POST https://69.195.x.x/
Attempting to connect to server 69.195.x.x:443
SSL negotiation with 69.195.x.x
SSL connection failure: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
Failed to open HTTPS connection to 69.195.x.x
GET https://69.195.x.x/
Attempting to connect to server 69.195.244.x:x
SSL negotiation with 69.195.x.x
SSL connection failure: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
Failed to open HTTPS connection to 69.195.x.x
```

I have some team mates who are using Windows AnyConnect client and I am able to connect to the VPN through the windows machine.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is by the last supported openconnect version in Ubuntu 14.04, that is openconnect 5.02.

There is a problem when you are trying to connect to newers versions of anyconnect server, so, there is a fix to solve it, it is installing the unsupported version of openconnect 7 in Ubuntu 14.04

You need to follow this steps to install openconnect 7:

**Preflight**

```
sudo apt-get install curl vpnc-scripts build-essential libssl-dev libxml2-dev liblz4-dev
curl -O ftp://ftp.infradead.org/pub/openconnect/openconnect-7.08.tar.gz
curl -O ftp://ftp.infradead.org/pub/openconnect/openconnect-7.08.tar.gz.asc
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-key 67e2f359
```

**Verify**

```
gpg --verify openconnect-7.08.tar.gz.asc
```

**Build**

```
tar xzf openconnect-7.08.tar.gz
cd openconnect-7.08
./configure --without-gnutls --with-vpnc-script=/usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

In this [guide](https://gist.github.com/darrenpmeyer/fa427b1ebdd8239bf665) you have all the detail.

Comment: Thank you @Kalamarico, this is exactly the problem I hit on Ubuntu 14.04. This should be marked as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use following command

```
sudo openconnect --user=%YOUR-USER% --no-xmlpost --interface=sslvpn --no-dtls %hostname%/%vpn_group_name%
```

Answer (score 0):

The pgp command command above failed for me because pgp.mit.edu wasn't working (server timeout), but I substituted keyserver.ubuntu.com in and it found the key.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).